# Froala fails on Ajax load of textarea after a few times using initialize and destroy

Tags: javascript, jquery, froala

To update some Blog Data, a click on an EDIT button initiates an Ajax call that loads a textarea for Froala and initialize Froala in the same routine.  It shows correctly.  I click on a submit button, which is another routine that destroys the Froala instance and empties the textarea to start over again on another blog.

This seems to work for a few cycles (1,2, or 3 - not consistent) of edit/submit, then fails and the textarea no longer renders as a Froala interface.

I do get a buildup of Javascript errors, but am having a difficult time understanding and tracing the source of them as most point to Jquery issues.  I suspect these are key, but maybe someone can point out something obvious as I struggle to understand these errors.  I'll post a few of them at the end.

```
//The textarea is appended to id="edit_data"
//It is: '<textarea id="article">{blog data here}</textarea>'
//this would be the (data) that comes through Ajax.
//HTML:
<div id="edit">
    <div id="edit_data"></div>    
</div>

//would get this after Ajax call
<div id="edit_data">
        <textarea id="article">{Froala blog data here}</textarea>
</div>    

//JS code when edit button clicked that appends textarea and initializes Froala
    $(document).on('click', '#edit_blog', function(){ 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'blog_list_ajax.php',
                async : false,
                data: { "action":'edit_blog',
                        "post_id":post_id},
                success: function(data) {
                        $('#edit_data').append(data);
                        $('#edit').fadeIn(1000);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Ajax Failed');
                }
            });

              // Froala Initialize action.
              if (!$('#article').data('froala.editor')) {
                $('#article').froalaEditor();
              } 
    });

//JS code when submit button clicked that destroys Froala and empties textarea
    $(document).on('click', '#update', function(){               
        //Destroy Froala instance        
        if ($('#article').data('froala.editor')) {
          $('#article').froalaEditor('destroy');
        }          
        $('#edit_data').empty();
        $('#edit').hide();
    });
```

Expecting that the Froala initialize and destroy should have done the trick even with loading in new `<textarea>`s each time.

JAVASCRIPT ERRORS:

```
VM17117:29 Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function
    at <anonymous>:29:7
    at <anonymous>:590:3
    at m (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.globalEval (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at text script (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Ut (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at k (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.send (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.ajax (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)

VM17119:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'POPUP_TEMPLATES' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:7:287
    at <anonymous>:7:240
    at <anonymous>:7:257
    at m (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.globalEval (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at text script (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Ut (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at k (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.send (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)

VM17120:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DEFAULTS' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:7:284
    at <anonymous>:7:240
    at <anonymous>:7:257
    at m (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.globalEval (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at text script (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Ut (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at k (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.send (VM17076 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

...There are more errors, but not sure how useful they will be to post here.

I should add that Froala gives a simple example of initialize and destroy [here](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/destroy-init).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above works fine.  The issue was a conflict with a double load of a header file containing several javascript(jquery, tagit, bootstrap, etc.) files, which caused error buildups to eventually cause odd behavior.  After correcting this issue, the Froala initiate/destroy function worked perfectly!